# How to filter logging of Flutter app in IntelliJ console?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

When developing a Flutter app - I'm mostly interested in the logging messages I create with `print()` - in this case the logger is called `I/flutter`(4th row in picture).
But I'm getting spammed by many other loggers as you can see below.

Is there an easy way to turn all other loggers besides `I/flutter` off and on?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now (18.09.2022) I don't see any of the checkboxes from the previous answers in IntelliJ anymore, so here's my current solution:
Instead of using IntelliJ to see my `print`s I...

1. Open Flutter DevTools:
   [image: Flutter DevTools]
2. Filter the logs manually by "stdout": [image: List item]
3. Enjoy it (until it randomly freezes and I have to re-open DevTools and filter manually again...)
   [image: List item]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Latest version of Android Studio doesn't carry this feature anymore.

---

Go to

```
Setting/Preferences -> Languages & Framework -> Flutter
```

Check

> Replace the Run and Debug console output with a custom Flutter Logging view

[image]

After that you'll be able to see your logs easily by using search functionality.

Comment: That feature is not available in Android Studio 3.6.2.

Comment: Info: nowadays with flutter 1.17.2 / IntelliJ 2020.1 this option doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Any solution for newer android studio versions?

Comment: @Ezra No that I am aware of.

Comment: cheapmunk laters version , there is no setting look like that ...so what the solutioin now ?

Answer (score -3):

## Update

You can simply go to debugger > Logcat output > and uncheck both

[image]

Comment: After I unchecked both I'm still getting annoying msgs like this: `W/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector( 5784): Touch pointer move a lot. The moving distance of X is:16.984253, limit is:60The moving distance of Y is:65.9657, limit is:60`